# Image will not update in code only custom control inheriting from button in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls, .net-4.5

I am currently trying to build a custom button control for a dice game I am writing in WPF. Everything is working correctly except that the image in the UI while it is running does not change when the  the die value has changed. I can confirm through my debug sessions that the image source is changing as expected as well as all values are changing as expected but the image just doesn't  seem to want to update.  I've tried looking over many similar questions but none of the questions seem to apply to my particular situation it would seem. I am new to WPF and not quite sure what I am doing wrong here...   my current code is as follows:

```
using BluffersDice.GameEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace BluffersDice.Interface.CustomControls
{
    public class DieButton : Button
    {  
        private Die _DieValue;
        private readonly BitmapImage ONE_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new  Uri("/res/dice/1.png",UriKind.Relative));
        private readonly BitmapImage TWO_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/res/dice/2.png", UriKind.Relative));
        private readonly BitmapImage THREE_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/res/dice/3.png", UriKind.Relative));
        private readonly BitmapImage FOUR_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/res/dice/4.png", UriKind.Relative));
        private readonly BitmapImage FIVE_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/res/dice/5.png", UriKind.Relative));
        private readonly BitmapImage SIX_IMAGE = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/res/dice/6.png", UriKind.Relative));
        private const string HELD_LABEL_TEXT = "Held";
        //private bool initcompleted = false;
        private Label HoldLabel { get; set; }       

        public DieButton() : this(new Die())
        {}

        public DieButton(Die dieValue)
        {
            Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(6);
            HoldLabel = new Label() { MinHeight = 15 };

            Click += This_OnClick;
            DieValueChanged += DieValueChangedHandler;
            dieValue.IsHeldChanged += DieValue_IsHeldChanged;
            dieValue.DieValueChanged += DieValueChangedHandler;
            _DieValue = dieValue;

            Panel = new StackPanel()
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                Margin = new Thickness(8)
            };

            DieImage = new Image() { Source = GetDieImageSource() };
            Panel.Children.Add(DieImage);           
            Panel.Children.Add(HoldLabel);
            Content = Panel;

            UpdateButtonContent();
            //initcompleted = true;
        }

        private void This_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DieValue.ToggleHold();
        }

        public event EventHandler DieValueChanged;

        public Die DieValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _DieValue;
            }
            set
            {
                _DieValue = value;
                if (DieValueChanged != null)
                {
                    DieValueChanged(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        private Image DieImage { get; set; }

        private StackPanel Panel { get; set; }

        private void DieValue_IsHeldChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var d = (Die)sender;

            if (d.IsHeld)
            {
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            }
            else
            {
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            }

            HoldLabel.Content = DieValue.IsHeld ?  HELD_LABEL_TEXT : string.Empty;
        }
        private void DieValueChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DieImage.Source = GetDieImageSource();
            UpdateButtonContent();

        }
        private ImageSource GetDieImageSource()
        {
            switch (DieValue.Value)
            {
                case 1:
                    return ONE_IMAGE;

                case 2:
                    return TWO_IMAGE;

                case 3:
                    return THREE_IMAGE;

                case 4:
                    return FOUR_IMAGE;

                case 5:
                    return FIVE_IMAGE;
                case 6:
                    return SIX_IMAGE;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        private void UpdateButtonContent()
        {
            (Panel.Children[0] as Image).Source = GetDieImageSource();   
        }
    }
}
```

**Window Is being used on:**

```
using BluffersDice.GameEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using BluffersDice.Interface.CustomControls;

namespace BluffersDice.Interface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserTurn.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PlayerTurn : Window
    {
        public Turn TurnState { get; set; }
        private Roll CurrentRoll { get; set; }

        public PlayerTurn()
        {
            CurrentRoll = new Roll();
            InitializeComponent();
            btn_Die1 = new DieButton(CurrentRoll.Dice[0]);
            btn_Die2 = new DieButton(CurrentRoll.Dice[1]);
            btn_Die3 = new DieButton(CurrentRoll.Dice[2]);
            btn_Die4 = new DieButton(CurrentRoll.Dice[3]);
            btn_Die5 = new DieButton(CurrentRoll.Dice[4]);
            GameState.Caller.StartNewTurn();

            TurnState = GameState.Caller.StartNewTurn();

            lbl_PlayerTitle.Text = string.Format(lbl_PlayerTitle.Text, GameState.Caller.Id);
        }

        private void btn_DieValuechanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            var d = (Die)sender;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Die Button {0} Value Changed To {1}", d.Id, d.Value));
        }
        private void DieValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var d = (Die)sender;
            //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Die {0} Value Changed To {1}", d.Id, d.Value));
        }

        private void RollDice_btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentRoll.RollDice();           
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: In WPF, you rarely need custom controls. Most likely, you can accomplish this behavior by styling or templating the button and putting your business logic into the view model.

Comment: While you rarely "need" custom controls, they are a nice way to encapsulate custom logic. Resource dictionaries are a pain and horribly inefficient, so encapsulating custom logic in a style or template inhibits re-usability. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Each time you want to change your image try  doing the below
    = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...

I have read around that usually works or you can follow the solution discussed here 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/976e8d89-aafd-4708-9e4f-87655a5da558

Comment: none of this seems to be working like i see the values getting there the image uri changing but nothing happens in the ui

Comment: i also tried dumping the value into a text label on the button as well and that value isn't updating either in the ui

Comment: but if i pop up a message box from inside the controll i can see that the values are there the wpf ui just doesn't update

Comment: Have you tried removing the the image container and adding a new one. Just want to see if that even works.

Comment: I think adding the images to your custom control via xaml might be a better way to go, that is it might be easier if changed images based off of visual states.

Comment: ya ive tried setting the image container to a new Image as well as simply setting the Source to a new BitmapImage as well interestingly the DieValue is not updating in UI either i know the value is changing  because i set a message box in the EventHandler for DieValueChanged but it doesn't change the UI value I'm pretty confident the events are being raised on a different thread but i don't know how to marshall the value to the ui thread

Comment: If you issue is with not being on the UI thread you can always call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.Invoke and update the image source.

Comment: i found a workaround for now...  if i manually invoke the changes from the calling ui class it works fine i will re address it later possibly  the invoking wasn't working for some reason but it seems to work fine if its called from an external click handler... weird   
this iteration  is due tonight so it will have to do for now. will fix later once i have the other functionality working this a interesting problem i would would really like solve will keep working on it in the coming days